# Want to find forecast based on the states, after performing box-cox and decomposition

Tags: python-3.x, time-series

I have a sample data where I have to forecast rain for next three years based on historical data. I have few locations and my algorithm should forecast for each state. Like for 'Boston' I have to perform Box - Cox transform, decompose it to trend, seasonality etc, then I have to reverse box-cox and I have to perform Exponential Smoothing or Linear, based on the number of observations. I have to do this for each state in the data frame. Could someone help me on this? Thanks in advance. Here is the sample data:

```
date    location    rain
1/1/2014    Texas   18.32963027
2/1/2014    Texas   19.92274329
3/1/2014    Texas   20.38279343
4/1/2014    Texas   27.3159539
5/1/2014    Texas   27.5645098
6/1/2014    Texas   27.5608686
7/1/2014    Texas   27.57887353
8/1/2014    Texas   29.5926802
9/1/2014    Texas   31.60648687
10/1/2014   Texas   33.93621112
11/1/2014   Texas   35.70541042
12/1/2014   Texas   36.65833393
1/1/2014    California  8.34339114
2/1/2014    California  8.692067027
3/1/2014    California  9.422258804
4/1/2014    California  9.214217859
5/1/2014    California  9.006176914
6/1/2014    California  9.604755883
7/1/2014    California  9.888033579
8/1/2014    California  10.16810799
9/1/2014    California  10.20382888
10/1/2014   California  10.51540693
11/1/2014   California  10.76762914
12/1/2014   California  11.76782392
1/1/2014    Delaware    21.20470244
2/1/2014    Delaware    24.68625493
3/1/2014    Delaware    24.8260787
4/1/2014    Delaware    25.51216229
5/1/2014    Delaware    26.00929879
6/1/2014    Delaware    26.96556932
7/1/2014    Delaware    28.91758644
8/1/2014    Delaware    30.15601303
9/1/2014    Delaware    30.16553625
10/1/2014   Delaware    30.12951079
11/1/2014   Delaware    32.08887564
12/1/2014   Delaware    37.02605358
1/1/2014    New York    2.41826977
2/1/2014    New York    2.444663247
3/1/2014    New York    2.623181528
4/1/2014    New York    2.352461354
5/1/2014    New York    3.094204612
6/1/2014    New York    2.751453486
7/1/2014    New York    2.838311136
8/1/2014    New York    2.912202885
9/1/2014    New York    3.905285108
10/1/2014   New York    3.963837011
11/1/2014   New York    4.118978426
12/1/2014   New York    4.413692115
1/1/2014    Nevada - East   26.8729
2/1/2014    Nevada - East   28.75562057
3/1/2014    Nevada - East   30.79926254
4/1/2014    Nevada - East   29.17065831
5/1/2014    Nevada - East   29.34811663
6/1/2014    Nevada - East   31.5466714
7/1/2014    Nevada - East   33.07517792
8/1/2014    Nevada - East   33.08263335
9/1/2014    Nevada - East   34.43932145
10/1/2014   Nevada - East   35.30577676
11/1/2014   Nevada - East   30.82206307
12/1/2014   Nevada - East   25.61649754
11/1/2014   Nevada - West   18.50768192
12/1/2014   Nevada - West   19.73764362
1/1/2014    Florida 4.793642983
2/1/2014    Florida 4.72996941
3/1/2014    Florida 5.028885069
4/1/2014    Florida 4.928489443
5/1/2014    Florida 5.567671082
6/1/2014    Florida 5.32194491
7/1/2014    Florida 6.171485467
8/1/2014    Florida 6.32027271
9/1/2014    Florida 6.919016794
10/1/2014   Florida 7.077980691
11/1/2014   Florida 7.249585352
12/1/2014   Florida 7.608819189
```

Comment: [Please do not post text as images.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3271649)

Instead, enter the text directly into your question.

Comment: @CtrlS I did enter the text directly. Thanks